# Which Angular Module turns [computed]="var" into computed="hello"?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using an excellent library to help me unit test components in Angular 5+ called [`shallow-render`](https://github.com/getsaf/shallow-render). By default, it automatically creates simple `{}` mocks for all your dependencies, unless you tell it not to (or define your own). (It doesn't mock `CoreModule` or `BrowserPlatformModule`).

I'm writing unit tests for components on an input and using the property binding syntax, like so:

```
<input [disabled]="condition" [type]="expression" ...>
```

In my app, the input has both `disabled` and `type` attributes (without the surrounding square brackets). In my tests, however, they do not appear. Instead, I only have the `ng-reflect-type` and `ng-reflect-disabled` attributes.

It appears that whatever module/dependency is responsible for adding the attributes into the template is not present. I would like to know which module it is so that I can tell `shallow-render` not to mock it.

Comment: This is what the compiler basically does. I guess, you can mock it but it won't render anything at all.

Comment: I don't want to mock it, @estus. I want my tests to have compiled components.

Comment: You can't do anything with it, this is how Angular compiler works. `[computed]=“var”` (it's not a real attribute) will be compiled to `computed` attribute on template compilation. If `var` is false, the attribute won't be added. ng-reflect-* attributes reflect only primitive values, they cannot be reliably asserted, so you'll need to assert inputs in child component any way.